# A continuously differentiable function is weakly differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, weak-derivatives

Define a *continuously differentiable* function to be a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ which has a *continuous* *derivative*. Define a weakly differentiable function to be a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ which is *locally integrable* and there exists $n$ *locally integrable* functions $g_1, \dots, g_n$ which satisfy the integration by parts formula, $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^p} f(x) \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_j} (x) \, \mathrm{d}x = - \int_{\mathbb{R}^p} g_j(x) \varphi(x) \, \mathrm{d}x,$$ for all $j \in \{1, \dots, n\}$ and for any function $\varphi$ that is any *infinitely differentiable* function with *compact support*.

I've come across the claim that "if a function $f$ is continuously differentiable, then it is weakly differentiable." How can that be true? Continuously differentiable functions needn't be locally integrable it seems.

Comment: Any continuous function is bounded on compact sets, and hence locally integrable.

Answer (score 0):

Continuously differentiable implies continuous implies measurable and bounded on compact sets which is equivalent to locally integrable.

Comment: Is the last equivalence correct? f(x)=|x|^{-1/2} is locally integrable on (-1,1) but not bounded on every compact subset of (-1,1).

Comment: That function is not continuous at $0$.